# What are the best practices for internationalizing a Java Swing desktop application?

Tags: java, swing, internationalization, desktop, locale

I'm sure there are a lot of methods, but what's the recommended way to do this that has the least amount of impact to your code?

The obvious is that you create properties files, but how do you swap the values in the rendering? In J2EE you always just re-render the whole page so it's easy. But in Swing apps, do you just add the code for the .getProperty() in the paintComponent(Graphics g) method?

If that's the case, doesn't it seem heavy since now you'll have to override this method everywhere where before you didn't need to...

***Additional:*** How do you setup a notification system to re-render all currently visible components without forcing some kind of registration pattern?

I guess if I overwrite paintComponent(Graphics g) all I have to do is fire an event that something has changed and the paintComponent(Graphics g) method will be called...

Comment: Easiest way: ask user to restart the program, for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I came up with was to create a massive registry of all components that would need to be re-rendered. Then if a call is made to switch Locale you can just call the registry and it will go through all the registered components and adjust their values. So for example for all the registered JLabels it will do something along the lines of

```
for(JLabel specificJLabel : REGISTRY.registeredJLabels)
{
  String localeKey = specificJLabel.getActionCommand();
  specificJLabel.setText(ResourceBundle.getString(localeKey)); 
}
```

where the Locale key is stored in the components ActionCommand. Then whatever screen is currently being rendered, the main parent panel is responsible for re-rendering it. Also this way the registry doesn't have to manage the Locale keys, these are completely decoupled from the registry. Each component is responsible to manage it's own Locale Keys to the ResourceBundle.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, some applications use layout/component **builders** (advised by Karsten Lentzsch, and part of [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/) API). These builders include the code to localize components (using `ResourceBundle` under the hood).

Other people (me included) prefer **resource injection**; this is normally the least intrusive method. This is the way chosen by the [Swing Application Framework](https://appframework.dev.java.net/) (JSR-296) and other GUI frameworks like [Guts-GUI](http://kenai.com/projects/guts/pages/Home).

You may also want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195533/swing-i18n-when-to-load-properties/3201050#3201050) which is quite similar to yours.

Regarding changes of language "on the fly" (`Locale` change notification), I think it is easier to implement when using resource injection (I have implemented this in Guts-GUI already, Swing Application Framework may also have it but I am not sure about it).

Java offers no way to listen to `Locale` changes, hence you have to create you own "Locale service" (which any Locale change request should be addressed to). In this service, you would have to enumerate all visible windows (this is possible with `Window.getWindows()`, no need to register visible components before) and then inject resources again.

If you want an example, take a look at the `resource` package in [Guts-GUI source code](http://guts.kenai.com/guts-gui/apidocs/):

- [ResourceInjector](http://guts.kenai.com/guts-gui/xref/net/guts/gui/resource/ResourceInjectorImpl.html) shows resource injection and method to change `Locale`, which sends a notification event (uses an **Event Bus** for that, but simple listeners would be fine too) about this change
- [WindowController](http://guts.kenai.com/guts-gui/xref/net/guts/gui/application/WindowControllerImpl.html) listens to Locale change events

The interesting code for updating all visible windows is copied hereafter:

```
for (Window window: Window.getWindows())
{
    if (window.isVisible())
    {
        injectResources(window);
        window.repaint();
        if (window instanceof RootPaneContainer)
        {
            ((RootPaneContainer) window).getRootPane().revalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Supporting dynamic language changes is a tricky problem. The simplest solution is to organise your UI in such a way that you can recreate any visible panels. That avoids the need to register or update components, when the language changes you simply recreate the view.

Obviously you lose the state of all visible components which may be an issue - but that is usually the same in a web app when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

Java 6 SE allows you to reload resource bundles on the fly.
Just call the `clearCache()` static function of the `ResourceBundle` class.
Then call `getBundle ()` again.

See [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/i18n_enhance/) under Cache Controls

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a ResourceBundle that allows you to have properties file based on Locale that you just access like a properties file.

[Here is a sample on how to do it](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0220__I18N/AnInternationalizedSwingApplication.htm)

Comment: I understand that, that's not really the question. The question is where do you call the ResourceBundle in the components so that it's rendered (or re-rendered) when needed. Is there another way than to overwrite paintComponent(Graphics g) on each JComponent?

Comment: @Stephane Grenier - Usually a user starts up a program in a different country and needs a different language based on the Locale he is in. Since as in the example you are adding the I18 stuff at construction it is going to be hard. You would need to change the locale and at least close the window and recreate it, or depending on the widget call setText() or whatever.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to be able to do it live, it's for a kiosk application I'm working on. I think I can do it by overriding the paintComponent methods, and with some careful thought. I was just hoping there was an easier method.