# java how to "refresh" gui after locale change

Tags: java, swing, locale

I am currently trying to localize/i18n my application and therefore I created a resource bundle containing one properties file for every language I want to support. Inside my settings tab you can change the language via a combobox and I tried to change the applications current locale as you can see in the following code.

```java
comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                switch (Objects.requireNonNull(comboBox.getSelectedItem()).toString()) {
                    case "Deutsch" -> Locale.setDefault(new Locale("de", "DE"));
                    case "English" -> Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));
                }

                repaint();
            }
        });
```

I was hoping repaint() would do the trick of changing all of the labels and stuff but it didn't work.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is a guess but try [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/UIDefaults.html#setDefaultLocale(java.util.Locale))

Comment: @g00se unfortunately didn't resolve the issue

Comment: This is another guess, but try repacking the `JFrame`.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc what exactly do you mean by repacking?

Comment: Call `frame.pack()` again.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc .pack() didn't show the desired result

Comment: unfortunately, Swing has no automatic update of localized properties - you have to implement it yourself (keep track of which properties need updates), see f.i. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810454/swing-internationalization-how-to-update-language-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to verify but I think that in order to use a different [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) you will need to explicitly load it and then re-set the text of all the components that get their text from the `ResourceBundle`.

From the `ResourceBundle` class *javadoc*:

> Resource bundle instances created by the `getBundle` factory methods are cached

In other words, your *properties* files are loaded only once.

Here is a sample that demonstrates. Method `changeLocale` is called whenever the `JComboBox` selection changes. The below code uses [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) and [switch expressions](https://openjdk.org/jeps/361).

My environment is JDK 19 on Windows 10.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyTable {
    private static final String KEY = "key";
    private static final String NAME;

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel label;
    private ResourceBundle rb;

    static {
        NAME = MyTable.class.getName().replace('.', '/');
    }

    public MyTable() {
        rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(NAME);
    }

    private void buildAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createCombo(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createLabel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void changeLocale(ActionEvent event) {
        JComboBox<?> combo = (JComboBox<?>) event.getSource();
        int index = combo.getSelectedIndex();
        Locale newLocale = switch (index) {
                               case 1 -> Locale.of("de", "DE");
                               default -> Locale.of("en", "US");
                           };
        rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(NAME, newLocale);
        label.setText(rb.getString(KEY));
    }

    private JPanel createCombo() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"Default", "German"});
        combo.addActionListener(this::changeLocale);
        panel.add(combo);
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createLabel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        label = new JLabel(rb.getString(KEY));
        panel.add(label);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new MyTable().buildAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

I have two *properties* files.

###### MyTable_en_US.properties

```
key=Address
```

###### MyTable_de_DE.properties

```
key=die Anschrift
```

[image: default]

---

[image: german]